# PowerShell scripting: Which attribute is for server location/name for a given user?

Tags: powershell, scripting, attributes

Can someone offer me up a hand to save me a little time?

I have a script I wrote which traverses a csv and exports all sorts of different attributes based on the users SAM_account_name. When I log in to the "active roles" admin console, under exchange properties, there is a field to see what mail server the account is currently on. e.g. USTS8123TU or something there of.

This should be an attribute *I think* and I want to include it in my export. I tried the obvious "serverName" but am pretty sure this is incorrect since the field does not return a value. Can someone with a little more experience who is perhaps more familiar with the attributes point me towards which one I am shooting for....

Here is a list of them: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx

There are so many!

Thanks....

Cory

Comment: I gave you the AD attribute name, but in general, it helps if you post your code in the question. That takes away a lot of the guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "based on the user's SAM_account_name", but if you're querying Active Directory, the attribute is **msExchHomeServerName**.

Comment: @user2008222 BTW, I noticed that you've accepted 3 answers but haven't cast any votes. I just want to point out, in case you weren't aware of it, that you can also upvote answers you accept (by clicking the up arrow above the number to the left of the answer). You generally should, unless for some reason you think the answer you accepted was marginal and you're accepting it only because it's "better than nothing".